# Change html page to .png

Tags: java, html, png

I want to change an html label I'm receiving from a site to a .png image.

This is the html I'm receiving:

```
    <html>

    <body>
       <div style='position: relative; margin-top: 25px; height: 800px;page-break-after: always;margin:0;padding:0;'>
          <table style="font-family:arial;">
            <tr>
              <td width="0px">&nbsp;</td>
              <td valign="top" width="626px">
                   <div style="position:absolute;">


                    <span style='left:356px;top:34px;position:absolute;'><img
                            src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFABgAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAUAGAAAAKKjI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7nwAiMJHXaEZphYJMK60UrGK0i9yPXI6l7cNxeAeUbsFLBXMKkzLUNDyhxaJRdpxdQ1dnFfmdRqVWIvkcE+XUP7S0i8aO4e46mLpj2rnszbK29/IVE2Dm8gchljio0iekYSiUJWgR2WD0WDZ5p2WJ55kZKjpKWmp66lIAADs%3D' /></span>


                    <span style='left:100px;top:0;position:absolute;font-size:12px;'><b>Responsible Delivery -
                            CO<sub>2</sub> Neutral</b></span>
                    <span style='left:196px;top:88px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Sender</span>
                    <span style='left:196px;top:96px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>MY CONTACT</span>
                    <span style='left:196px;top:105px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>ROEBUCK LANE</span>
                    <span style='left:196px;top:114px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>SMETHWICK</span>
                    <span style='left:196px;top:123px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>BIRMINGHAM</span>
                    <span style='left:196px;top:132px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'></span>
                    <span style='left:196px;top:141px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>B66 1BY</span>
                    <span style='left:242px;top:145px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Phone:0121 500 2500</span>
                    <span style='left:250px;top:88px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Account:103092</span>

                    <span style='left:4px;top:19px;position:absolute;font-size:12px;'>USER NAME</span>
                    <span style='left:4px;top:30px;position:absolute;font-size:12px;'>ADDRESS LINE 1</span>
                    <span style='left:4px;top:41px;position:absolute;font-size:12px;'></span>
                    <span style='left:4px;top:52px;position:absolute;font-size:12px;'>CITY LONDON</span>
                    <span style='left:4px;top:63px;position:absolute;font-size:12px;'></span>
                    <span style='left:4px;top:74px;position:absolute;font-size:12px;'>ZIP 123</span>
                    <span style='left:90px;top:74px;position:absolute;font-size:12px;'>United Kingdom</span>
                    <span style='left:220px;top:68px;position:absolute;font-size:18px;'></span>
                    <span style='left:4px;top:88px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Contact</span>
                    <span style='left:4px;top:96px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Phone</span>
                    <span style='left:4px;top:120px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Consignment</span>
                    <span style='left:4px;top:128px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Ref</span>
                    <span style='left:4px;top:104px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Info</span>

                    <span style='left:60px;top:104px;font-size:8px;position:absolute;'></span>
                    <span style='left:60px;top:112px;font-size:8px;position:absolute;'></span>

                    <span style='left:60px;top:88px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>USER NAME</span>
                    <span style='left:60px;top:96px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>7420000000</span>
                    <span style='left:60px;top:120px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>3907367566</span>
                    <span style='left:60px;top:128px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>TESTORDERASM</span>
                    <span style='left:60px;top:136px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'></span>
                    <span style='left:60px;top:144px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'></span>

                    <span style='left:284px;top:18px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Packages</span>
                    <span style='left:276px;top:48px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Total Weight</span>
                    <span style='left:274px;top:26px;position:absolute;font-size:16px;'>1 of 1</span>
                    <span style='left:274px;top:56px;position:absolute;font-size:16px;'>2 kg</span>

                    <span style='left:6px;top:180px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Track</span>
                    <span style='left:350px;top:180px;position:absolute;font-size:8px;'>Service</span>
                    <span style='left:5px;top:158px;position:absolute;font-size:22px;'>1550</span>
                    <span style='left:62px;top:160px;position:absolute;font-size:16px;'>3907 3675 66F</span>
                    <span
                        style='left:5px;width:370px;top:250px;position:absolute;font-size:10px;text-align:center;'>
                        25/10/19 08:23 Web 4.3.3-api </span>
                    <span style='left:19px;top:265px;position:absolute;'><img width='348px' height='95px'
                    src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAegAAAAOCAMAAADT5H8VAAADAFBMVEX///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALI7fhAAABAHRSTlP//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKmfXxgAAGslJREFUeNoBvhpB5QABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQABAQEBAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAEBAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAEBAAABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAABAQEBAQEAAAAAAQEBAQAAAQEAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAAAAAEBAQEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAQEBAAAAAAAAAQEBAQEBAAABAQAAAQEBAXI3DSFwaxO9AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC' /></span>
                    <span style='left:85px;top:363px;position:absolute;font-size:12px;'>BT48 7ER1 5503 9073 6756
                        6812 826U</span>
                    <span
                        style='left:132px;top:158px;width:250px;text-align:right;position:absolute;font-size:20px;'>
                        NEXT DAY</span>
                    <span style='left:130px;top:230px;position:absolute;font-size:14px;'> 812-GB - BT48 7ER </span>
                    <span style='left:10px;top:190px;position:absolute;font-size:18px;'></span>
                    <span style='left:10px;top:225px;position:absolute;font-size:30px;'></span>
                    <span style='left:300px;top:225px;position:absolute;font-size:30px;'>0087</span>
                    <span style='left:45px;top:180px;position:absolute;font-size:46px;'>GB-BT48 7ER</span>

                    <table
                        style='display:inline-block;border:3px solid black;padding:0;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;'
                        height='385' width='385px'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table style='padding:0;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;' width='100%'>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style='font-size:1px;border-bottom:1px solid black;' colspan='4'>
                                            <div style='height:10px'>&nbsp;</div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan='2'
                                            style='text-align:left;border-bottom:1px solid black;vertical-align:top;'>
                                            <div style='height:69px'>&nbsp;</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style='border-bottom:1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;'>
                                            &nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style='border-bottom:3px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;'
                                            rowspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style='border-bottom:3px solid black;'>
                                            <div style='height:66px'>&nbsp;</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style='border-bottom:3px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;'
                                            colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style='text-align:left;vertical-align:top;' colspan='4'>
                                            <div style='height:226px'>&nbsp;</div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style='font-size:1px;' width='195px'>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style='font-size:1px;' width='70px'>
                                            <div style='height:1px'>&nbsp;</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style='font-size:1px;' width='80px'>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style='font-size:1px;' width='40px'>&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried the below code:

```
     HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator();
      String uri = new File("D:/3907367566.html").toURI().toString();

        try {
            imageGenerator.loadHtml(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D:/3907367566.html"))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageGenerator.setOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        imageGenerator.saveAsImage("D:/3907367566_2.png");
        imageGenerator.saveAsHtmlWithMap("3907367566.html", "3907367566.png");
```

Please check the screenshot original .html page and the .png file I'm getting here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VGgKwGkmSijKZWjhZADNLxCcBWOcY7f0/view?usp=sharing

Can anyone help me create an image that is exactly the same as the HTML we are receiving? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working properly. The issue is that your are not downloading the CSS style sheet and other resources like images (the barcode).

Despite having lots of styling embedded to your HTML file, it is clearly losing some styling rules.

One solution would be to embed all the CSS properties into your HTML.

Another one would be to use an external API like: https://htmlcsstoimage.com/ which accepts CSS and HTML.